# How to use regexp search a string following a multi-line pattern in Vim?

Tags: regex, vim

I have a text document which exists some pieces of string following a multi-line pattern:

```
fdcxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
fdcxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxVOLxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

"x" represents blanks, digits, letters and other symbols. And I only want to match the second `fdc` to `VOL`.

I tried to use the regexp such as `"fdc\_.*VOL"` which will match the first `fdc` to VOL. But if use `"fdc\_.*?VOL"`, I'll get nothing.

Comment: Well, in Vim, a lazy quantifier is `\{-}`, not `*?`. However, it won't work since the engine works from left to right. Try `fdc\(\(fdc\)\@!\_.\)\{-}VOL`

Comment: so you want to search `fdc...(without any other fdc)... VOL` or `fdc .. fdc (without any other fdc)... VOL`? If the first fdc condition is required?

Comment: `fdc...(without any other fdc) ... VOL`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
/fdc\(\(fdc\)\@!\_.\)\{-}VOL
```

Or, if you prefer less escaping in regex, use "very magic mode":

```
/\vfdc((fdc)@!\_.){-}VOL
```

**Details**

- `fdc` - matches `fdc`
- `\(` - starting a group:

  - `\(fdc\)\@!` - check if there is no `fdc` immediately to the right of the current position (aka "negative lookahead" in common regex)
  - `\_.` - any 1 char
- `\)\{-}` - ending the group and make it match 0 or more times, but as few as possible (`\{-}` is like `*?` in common regex)
- `VOL` - a `VOL` substring.

See the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I like the regular syntax, but it is certainly possible to use `/\vfdc((fdc)@!\_.){-}VOL`